# TYPO3 constants setup Backend start view

Tags: typoscript, typo3-extensions

I have build with the extension builder (exb) a simple new extension with a backend module.  
The exb creates different views for the backend under

> ../Resources/Private/Backend/...

but if I start the backend, it does not use the view under the backend folder.

In constant.ts

```
module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe {
view {
    # cat=module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (BE)
    templateRootPath = EXT:hgaimage/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
    # cat=module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (BE)
    partialRootPath = EXT:hgaimage/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
    # cat=module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (BE)
    layoutRootPath = EXT:hgaimage/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
}
persistence {
    # cat=module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
    storagePid =
}
```

}

In setup.ts

```
module.tx_hgaimage_tools_hgaimagehgaimagebe {
persistence {
    storagePid = {$module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe.persistence.storagePid}
}
view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:hgaimage/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
    templateRootPaths.1 = {$module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe.view.templateRootPath}
    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:hgaimage/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
    partialRootPaths.1 = {$module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe.view.partialRootPath}
    layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:hgaimage/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    layoutRootPaths.1 = {$module.tx_hgaimage_hgaimagebe.view.layoutRootPath}
}
```

}

The difference is, that in setup is for the tools and one for the tools an additional .0 for each path definition.

For both ../Backend/.. is defined, but this views are not used.

Why are very simular definitions in setup and constants?
What could be the problem that not the views under backend are used?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with not using ../Backend/.. I solved. Additing the "Include static from extension" on the template.

But why these different setups neccessary?